# Impact on expected frequency of yellow & red balls of drawing blue ball after yellow ball

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a opaque urn holding a finite number of balls. I am asked:  "Are there more balls marked A or B"?

The first ball I pull out is marked A-  so, at that point, it seems more likely that there are more A balls than B balls.  I do not replace the first ball.

I pull out a second ball, which is marked "C".

Should that "second pull" increase my confidence that there are more A balls than B balls?

Comment: To predict that you'd pull more balls.

Comment: My sense is that having the second ball marked "C" should increase my confidence that there are more A balls than B balls, since I reduced the number of balls remaining in the urn, and still have only retrieved an A ball and no B ball, i.e., the ratio of A balls I pulled out to the total number of balls remaining in the urn has increased.  I'd appreciate it if someone could validate (or contradict) this.

Comment: Suppose n(A)=n(B), even if A occurs, doesn't mean n(A) is more.

Comment: Hermant-  I'm not sure I understand.  Are you saying that my expectation of whether there are more A balls or B balls should not be influenced by my initial drawing of an A ball?

Comment: Exactly! Draw some more balls... The more you have info., the better you get prediction.

Comment: Hemant- Yes, of course, drawing more balls will give you a better prediction. Drawing one A ball gives you a better prediction than not having drawn any balls at all. It doesn't tell you that n(A) is necessarily greater than n(B), but it does tell you that, if you have to bet on either n(A) or n(B) being greater, you'd be better off betting that n(A) is greater.

Comment: If I  compulsory to bet, then Yes!